# Spring get the value from other method when called

Tags: java, spring, service

Implementation:
In Service1 will return a Value in Service2 in the method transerValue but when CalledLaterMethod will later be called but when i try to access transerValue inside CalledLaterMethod its null.
Is there possible way to store the value in transerValue  and wait CalledLaterMethod being called and get the value? For any solution kindly let me know

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Class1{

  private String param1;
  private String param2;

}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Class2{

  private String param4;
  private String param5;

}
```

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class Service1{


// with method for validationString
  
  
  
  public Class1 validationString(String val1, String val2){
  
        String present = "PRESENT";
        String empty = "EMPTY";

        String param1Transfer = "";
        String param2Transfer = "";
        
         if(val1.isEmpty()) param1Transfer = empty;
        else param1Transfer = present;
        if(val2.isEmpty()) param2Transfer = empty;
        else param2Transfer = present;
         Class1 class1 = Class1.builder()
                .param1(param1Transfer)
                .param2(param2Transfer)
                .build();
        return Service2.transerValue(class1);

  }

}
```

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class Service2{

   public static Class1 transerValue(Class1 class1){
   //log will work
   log.info("Well this data show ={}",class1 );
   return class1;
   }
   
   //this method CalledLaterMethod will be called later and i must get the value being transfer in transerValue
   // and must not change the parameter of CalledLaterMethod
   public static Class2 CalledLaterMethod(OtherClass1 other1,OtherClass other2 ){
   
   // i tried
   //this is null
   Class1 class1 = new Class1();
   Class1 classClone = transerValue(class1)
   log.info(classClone);
   
   //trying to do
   
  Class2 class2 = Class2.builder.
   .param4(classClone.getParam1)
   .param5(classClone.getParam2)
   build();
   
   return class2;
   
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will always get null since you don't set any value in class1 in CalledLaterMethod, in that class you just instantiate object class1 without set the value in that object, unless you pass the value class1 from parameter in CalledLaterMethod. I assume OtherClass1 is Class1 object which will be passed, you can do something like this if you don't want to change the parameter in CalledLaterMethod

```java
public class Service2{
    
       public static Class1 transerValue(Class1 class1){
       //log will work
       log.info("Well this data show ={}",class1 );
       return class1;
       }
       
       //this method CalledLaterMethod will be called later and i must get the value being transfer in transerValue
       // and must not change the parameter of CalledLaterMethod
       public static Class2 CalledLaterMethod(OtherClass1 other1,OtherClass other2 ){
       
       // assign object from parameter to a new object called class1
       Class1 class1 = other1;
       Class1 classClone = transerValue(class1)
       log.info(classClone);
       
       //trying to do
       
      Class2 class2 = Class2.builder.
       .param4(classClone.getParam1)
       .param5(classClone.getParam2)
       build();
       
       return class2;
       
       }

    }
```